# How to understand "m ()" is a monadic computation

Tags: haskell, monads

From the [document](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#Conditional_monadic_computations):

```
when :: (Monad m) => Bool -> m () -> m ()
when p s = if p then s else return ()
```

The `when` function takes a boolean argument and a monadic computation with unit `()` type and performs the computation only when the boolean argument is `True`.

===

As a Haskell newbie, my problem is that for me `m ()` is some "void" data, but here the document mentions it as computation. Is it because of the laziness of Haskell?

Comment: Be aware that the word [void](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7.1/docs/Data-Void.html) has a technical meaning in this _domain_ (pun intended), and is not the same as the unit type `()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laziness has no part in it.

The `m`/Monad part is often called *computation*.

The best example might be `m = IO`:

Look at [`putStrLn "Hello" :: IO ()`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) - This is a computation that, when run, will print `"Hello"` to your screen.

This computation has no result - so the return type is `()`

Now when you write

```
hello :: Bool -> IO ()
hello sayIt =
   when sayIt (putStrLn "Hello")
```

then `hello True` is a computation that, when run, will print `"Hello"`; while `hello False` is a computation that when run will do nothing at all.

---

Now  compare it to [`getLine :: IO String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine) - this is a computation that, when run, will prompt you for an input and will return the input as a `String` - that's why the return type is `String`.

Does this help?

Comment: usually when function get called, the parameters are calculated first (some maybe like generator/lazy list stuff not get a full result). I'm stucked with why the "m ()" not "calculated/called“ first as usual.

Comment: the `()` in `m ()` is not a function argument - it a type-argument (in this case it might be unfortunate that the *only* value of the unit type is written the same as the type: `() :: ()`) but really `()` here is the unit type - see a Monad `m` is not a type it is something you have to give another type to produce a type (we say it has kind `* -> *`) - and the way you do it is just as with functions - with a *space* - so `IO` is not a type but `IO ()` and `IO String` are

Comment: Why do you write `putStrLn "Hello" :: IO String`? It should be `putStrLn "Hello" :: IO ()`.

Comment: @Carsten, okay I understand that printStrLn is a compuation. then how the compuation is "called"?  Why the "then s" syntax will call the compuation instead of just return the compuation?

Comment: @arsane The computation is not "called". The function `when` takes a computation and returns one. Depending on the outcome of the `Bool`, the returned computation is either identical to the computation you passed in, or it is a computation that does nothing (i.e., `return ()`).

Comment: it actually will return it (the other branch returns a computation that does nothing) ...

Comment: @Carsten, my question might be: why "putStr str" isn't called before when? I guess this is becoz of laziness?

Comment: well it would not actually evaluate this branch to get the computation-value  because of lazyness yes - but in this case even if it would you would not see any text on the screen, because you will only see it when the computation is run

Comment: @Carsten so the "then s" part will "run" the computation, How this is done?  Is it related with haskell's evaluation model?

Comment: well you can think of it like this: the `main` function of your programm has type `IO ()` and you chain all computations in there together - the computation `main` itself will then be run when you execute your program!   That is the only place where anything will run - all else is just composing computations

Comment: for other monads you will eventually run the computation with some function provided with it - for example you will run `State` computations when you call [`evalState`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:evalState) (or some other function there) - you can recognize those functions easily: they will have the monad on the left/input side but not on the right/output side ;)

Comment: @Carsten thanks, I think this execution model is the key of my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

> for me "m ()" is some "void" data

And that kinda makes sense, in that a computation *is* a special kind of data. It has nothing to do with laziness - it's associated with context.

Let's take `State` as an example. A function of type, say, `s -> ()` in Haskell can only produce one value. However, a function of type `s -> ((), s)` is a regular function doing some transformation on `s`. The problem you're having is that you're only looking at the `()` part, while the `s -> s` part stays hidden. That's the point of `State` - to hide the state passing.

Hence `State s ()` is trivially convertible to `s -> ((), s)` and back, and it still is a `Monad` (a computation) that produces a value of... `()`.

If we look at practical use, now:

```
(flip runState 10) $ do
    modify (+1)
```

This expression produces a tuple of `((), Int)`; the `Int` part is hidden

It will modify the state, adding 1 to it. It produces the intermediate value of `()`, though, which fits your `when`:

```
when (5 > 3) $ modify (+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Monads are notably abstract and mathematical, so intuitive statements about them are often made in language that is rather vague.  So values of a monadic type are often informally labeled as "computations," "actions" or (less often) "commands" because it's an analogy that sometimes help us reason about them.  But when you dig deeper, these turn out to be empty words when used this way; ultimately what they mean is "some value of a type that provides the `Monad` interface."

I like the word "action" better for this, so let me go with that.  The intuition for the use for that word in Haskell is this: the language makes a distinction between **functions** and **actions**:

1. Functions can't have any side effects, and their types look like `a -> b`.
2. Actions may have side effects, and their types look like `IO a`.

   - A consequence of this: an action of type `IO ()` produces an uninteresting result value, and therefore it's either a no-op (`return ()`) or an action that is only interesting because of its side effects.

`Monad` then is the interface that allows you to glue actions together into complex actions.

This is all very intuitive, but it's an analogy that becomes rather stretched when you try to apply it to many monads other than the `IO` type.  For example, lists are a monad:

```
instance Monad [] where
  return a = [a]
  as >>= f = concatMap f as
```

The "actions" or "computations" of the list monad are... lists.  How is a list an "action" or a "computation"?  The analogy is rather weak in this case, isn't it?

So I'd say that this is the best advice:

1. Understand that "action" and "computation" are analogies.  There's no strict definition.
2. Understand that these analogies are stronger for some monad instances, and weak for others.
3. The ultimate barometer of how things work are the `Monad` laws and the definitions of the various functions that work with `Monad`.

Comment: @Lius Casillas, I really like your answer, it clear up concept. Also, I think the document mentioned "Perform" the compuation which maybe not correct, the when only return "m ()", the "perform of the computation" is done by outside by either call monad function or like IO monad will be called through main entry.